# HTML to Text Converter for Email Template (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, text, process

I want make javascript HTML converter to Text. All done I works good, but I can't process links. I need the reg expression which is make in text version link as

Html version:

```
<a href="http://link.com">Link text</a>
```

convert link to Text version:

```
Link text(http://link.com)
```

My code

```
$('body').on('click','[data-action="convertTemplateToText"]', function() {
    var html = $("#clientHTML").val();

    if (html) {
        html = html.replace(/<!doctype.*>/i,"");
        html = html.replace(/<head>[\w\W]*?<\/head>/i,"");
        html = html.replace(/<style.*>[\w\W]*?<\/style>/gi,"");
        html = html.replace(/<script.*>[\w\W]*?<\/script>/gi,"");
        html = html.replace(/\n|\r/g," ");
        html = html.replace(/\<\/p\>/gi,"\n");
        html = html.replace(/\<\/li\>/gi," ");
        html = html.replace(/\<br\s*?\/?\>/gi,"\n");
        html = strip_tags(html,'<a>');
        html = html_entity_decode(html,'HTML_ENTITIES');
        html = html.replace(/([ \t])+/g," ");
        html = html.replace(/\n /g,"\n");

        if (html.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            html = html.substr(1);
        }
    } else {
        html = '';
    }

    $("#clientText").val(html);
    $('#templateTextContainer').slideDown(500);

    return false;
});
```

Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're using jQuery or not, but with it it's pretty simple:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $text = $(this).html();
    var $link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).after($text+" ("+$link+")");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

EDIT3 (corrected error from comment):

OK, I've achieved what you need:

```
/<\s*a.*?href\s*=\s*(?:"|')(.*?)(?:"|')[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*?\/\s*?a\s*?>/ig
```

And the substitution would be:

```
$2 ($1)
```

Here's a working example: http://regexr.com/38qgv

I've also added a check to include malformed tags such as `<   a href  =  "">` or `<  / a >`

Comment: nope...I need in reg exp. I got value with textarea and after working with text and in this text I should replace all links, but thanks for answer

Comment: http://regexr.com/38qf9 - check this link please. if links make in one line then reg exp is not work correct :(

Comment: Are you here ? Can you help me ?

Comment: I've just edited the link in my answer try it out now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TextVersionJS](http://textversionjs.com/) which is an open source lib that solves the very same problem, you have. It does not depend on any other libs, and you can use it in the browser and in node.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <body>
      <div id='tempDiv'></div>
        <script>
          var html
          html='<h3><a href="//stackoverflow.com">current community</a></h3>'
          alert(toText(html))
```

The following function converts to text any html content passed to it

```
            function toText(content) {
             document.getElementById('tempDiv').innerHTML = content
             return document.getElementById('tempDiv').textContent
            }
        </script>

     </body>
    </html>
```